# How to tell a story with feature specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

It seems that the current state of your application is 'reset' between specs. I don't want this to happen, because I want to be able to 'tell a story': user_0 does this, then he does that, then he decides to delete this, and only then does he log out. I want to have expectations at every one of these points

If you have an expectation like this:

```
scenario "user_0 signs up with correct credentials" do      
    sign_up( @a999.first_name, @a999.last_name, @a999.profile_name, @a999.email, @a999.password )
    expect(page).to have_content("Welcome, " + @a999.full_name + "!")    

    sign_up( @a699.first_name, @a699.last_name, @a699.profile_name, @a699.email, @a699.password )
    expect(page).to have_content("Welcome, " + @a699.full_name + "!")
end
```

it fails, because user @a999 is already signed in, so we can't sign in another user. If we write capybara code to `sign_out` @a999 then it passes, as we'd expect.

That's fine, that's the behaviour I'd expect. But if split the two sign sequences into separate expectations, something a little strange happens.

```
scenario "user signs up with correct credentials" do      
    sign_up( @a999.first_name, @a999.last_name, @a999.profile_name, @a999.email, @a999.password )
    expect(page).to have_content("Welcome, " + @a999.full_name + "!")    
end

scenario "user signs up with correct credentials" do         
    sign_up( @a699.first_name, @a699.last_name, @a699.profile_name, @a699.email, @a699.password )
    expect(page).to have_content("Welcome, " + @a699.full_name + "!")
end
```

**Basically, the expectations both pass, which has lead be to conclude that the application is 'reset' between expectations.**

**But I don't want this to happen, I want to tell a story, so how do I do this?**

Is the answer to user contexts, like this:

```
context "user_a999 signs up"
    before(:all) {
        sign_up( @a999.first_name, @a999.last_name, @a999.profile_name, @a999.email, @a999.password )     
    }

    scenario "has welcome message" do
        expect(page).to have_content("Welcome, " + @a999.full_name + "!")    
    end

        context "user_a999 signs out" do
            before(:all) {
                sign_out
            }

            scenario "has sign_out message" do
                 expect(page).to have_content("Signed out user " + @a999.full_name )                
            end

            context "user @a444 signs up" do
                before(:all) {
                    sign_up( @a444.first_name, @a444.last_name, @a444.profile_name, @a444.email, @a444.password )  
                }
            end

                context "user @a444" do
                    before(:all) {
                        visit "userfriendships/new/" + @a699.id
                    }

                    scenario "makes friend" do
                        click_link "confirm friend"
                        expect(page).to have_content( @a444.full_name + " and " + @a699.full_name + "are now friends!")
                    end    

                    scenario "deny friend" do
                        click_link "deny friend"
                        expect(page).to have_content( @a444.full_name + " and " + @a699.full_name + " are now denied a friendship!")
                    end    

                end
        end
end
```

Using contexts does work, and I like how it's organised, a bit like a probability tree, but the reason I'm asking about this way is for two reasons:

1) With intricate expectations, the indentation of each context will be insane. Within a few nested contexts you'll need to scroll way over to the right in your text editor to be able to read the code. I mean, I understand how to use contexts to set up the application in a certain state, but this is an integration spec, which is meant to test my whole stack. I don't want to hit active record immediately, I want to go through the form with capybara.

2) It doesn't read well. `scenario "has welcome message"` doesn't really make sense, so I'd be grateful for some clarification.

Comment: `It seems that the current state of your application...` Whose application? Is this copy-and-pasted from something?

Comment: The one you're working on. I'm not being facetious, but are you not an native English speaker? It's pretty obvious what I mean by that

Comment: Sorry, really didn't mean anything by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, an integration test is different from an acceptance test which is what feature specs are.

Anyway, when writing specs, you should have separate spec files for each feature you are to test. In your code sample, you should test the "Signing in" feature in a separate feature spec file from the "Friend Requests" feature spec file. Your "Friend Requests" spec would look somewhat like this:

```
feature 'Friend Requests' do
  let(:user) { User.make! } #using Machinist
  let(:other_user) { User.make! }

  background do
    sign_in(user) #have a helper method for sign_in
    #code for other_user to send friend request to user
  end

  scenario "accept friend request" do
    #code for user to accept friend request
  end

  scenario "deny friend request" do
    #code for user to deny friend request
  end
end
```

Feature specs are acceptance tests and as such, aren't meant to work like unit tests where there should only be one assertion per test. In an acceptance test, you could have multiple assertions in one test since they run much slower.

When your `context`s become too deeply nested, that's usually a sign that you have to break up your tests into separate specs. I try to stick with using just one `context` nesting for easier readability.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah definite help! Quick question, is Machinist similar to Factory Girl?

Comment: @Starkers, that's correct. I just prefer to use Machinist since I think it's simpler but they're both interchangeable.